# Cloud Functionsdeploy (Unexpected tocken) I'm getting error (30:37 error Parsing error: Unexpected token followedUserRef) when I deploy my code

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, backend

I trying to get and add documents to firestore database using clound functions (Nodejs). but I get error every time when I deploy my code.

```
exports.onCreateFollower = functions.firestore.document("/followers/{userId}/userFollers/{followerId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        console.log("Follower created", snapshot.data);
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const followerId = context.params.followerId;

        // get followed users post
        const followedUserPostRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(userId).collection('userPosts');

        // get following users time line
        const timelinePostRef =  admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('timeline')
            .doc(followerId)
            .collection('timelinePosts');

        // get the followed users posts
        const querysnapshot = await followedUserPostRef.get();

        // add each user posts to users timeline
        querysnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                const postId = doc.id;
                const postData = doc.data();
                timelinePostRef.doc(postId).set(postData);
            }
        });
    });
```

i get error given below...

`
**
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint C:\Users\Yousuf Khan\Documents\flutter\instagram_clone\functions
> eslint .

C:\Users\Yousuf Khan\Documents\flutter\instagram_clone\functions\index.js
30:37  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token followedUserRef

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yousuf Khan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-04T07_21_32_055Z-debug.log
events.js:291
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
**
`

Comment: Is this your whole code? The error hints at there being a reference to `followedUserRef` instead of `followedUserPostRef` which is undefined and that is why the error pops out, but the code you share does have such reference so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//oncreate function should be async
exports.onCreateFollower = functions.firestore.document("/followers/{userId}/userFollers/{followerId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        console.log("Follower created", snapshot.data);
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const followerId = context.params.followerId;

        // get followed users post
        const followedUserPostRef = admin.firestore().collection('posts').doc(userId).collection('userPosts');

        // get following users time line
        const timelinePostRef =  admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('timeline')
            .doc(followerId)
            .collection('timelinePosts');

        // get the followed users posts
        //I have used await here
        const querysnapshot = await followedUserPostRef.get();

        // add each user posts to users timeline
        querysnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                const postId = doc.id;
                const postData = doc.data();
                timelinePostRef.doc(postId).set(postData);
            }
        });
    });
```

I have used await word before followedUserPostRef.get(). so i have to make this function async. i haven't done that thats why error occure.